# arara/luatex: set subfolders for output PDF file and all auxiliary files

Tags: luatex, arara

The following directives are able to properly generate the output PDF file. However, I would like to set, for instance, one folder for PDF file (Output) and another one for all auxiliary files (Aux).

How can it be smoothly done and let `luatex` and `biber` recognize the subfolders?

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex
% arara: lualatex
```

Comment: Would https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any be an alternative for you? It will place all the auxiliary files in another folder and is still able to work with them. So it does not run the sequence of lualatex, biber, 2*lualatex everytime, but only the necassary tools. And even with the auxiliary files not present in folder of the document, it takes care to modify the synctex files accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration, I think I got the help to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set `aux/output` directories using `arara`, the following should be written (in case you want a folder named `PDF` for the output PDF file and another folder named `AuxDirectory` for aux files)

```
% arara: lualatex: { options: "-output-directory=PDF -aux-directory=AuxDirectory" }
% arara: biber: { options: "--input-directory AuxDirectory --output-directory AuxDirectory" }
% arara: lualatex: { options: "-output-directory=PDF -aux-directory=AuxDirectory" }
% arara: lualatex: { options: "-output-directory=PDF -aux-directory=AuxDirectory" }
```

It is very important to make sure that the new aux directory (which is `AuxDirectory` here) has a subfolder named after the subfolder you include the files from (`SourceFiles` here).